Moving SSISdb to the new drive on the same server
I  am trying to move SSISdb to the new drives on the same server. I know how to move the user databases but I couldn't find a proper way to move ssisdb.
can anyone please help me with clear steps about moving ssisdb to another drive please.
thanks in advance
